# What is the best way of connecting electricity fuse/cut-out

Tags: electrical, fuses

I am talking about home/industrial electrical fuse fitting or correct mointing . Should the fuse be mounted on L(live) wire or N(neutral) wire?.

Comment: When the fuse blows, do you want both wires to be live or both wires to be neutral?

Comment: This kind of information is all spelled out in the applicable building codes. In the US, that would be the [National Electrical Code](https://catalog.nfpa.org/NFPA-70-National-Electrical-Code-NEC-Softbound-P1194.aspx?order_src=G010&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIp-bH267S6gIVU-DICh28jgO5EAAYASAAEgImX_D_BwE), published by the [National Fire Protection Association](https://www.nfpa.org/). You generally need to be a licensed electrician to do this kind of work, in which case, you wouldn't need to ask this kind of question here.

Answer (score 1):

From a safety viewpoint, only the lines (L) should be fused and not the neutral (N).

In the case of a line short to neutral or ground, the fuse will blow and prevent a fire. In the case of a line short to a grounded metal enclosure, the fuse will blow and prevent exposure of personnel to an electrical safety hazard.